# Add database value in views for entity type user

Tags: views, entities

I want to extend the user profile with a rank (a decimal ranging from 500 - 2500), which needs to be updated on a regular basis (10 times per minute) for several users. (it is for http://achtungdiekurve.net/ ) I already implemented it with a seperate table, containing a rank field and implemented a table to show the rankings (http://achtungdiekurve.net/ranks ).

However, I want to use views to create this table. But I cant seem to alter the entity type user in such a way, that it shows Rank in the views forms. How to do this? My current code:

```
<?php
function achtung_entity_property_info_alter(&$info) {

  $info["user"]["properties"]["rank"] = array(
    "label" => t("Rank"),
    "description" => t("The rank of the user"),
    "type" => "decimal",
    "getter callback" => "achtung_get_entity_callback",
    "computed" => true,
    "entity views field" => true,
    "query callback" => "entity_property_query",
  );
  watchdog("ACHTUNG entity info alter", "<pre>".print_r($info, true)."</pre>");
  return $info;

}
function achtung_get_entity_callback($account, $options, $name, $entity_type) {
  watchdog("ACHTUNG entity info callback", "<pre>".print_r($account, true)."</pre>");
  return 2;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I haven't had a chance to play with it myself just yet, assuming everything else is implemented correctly, it seems as though using [EntityFieldQuery Views Backend](http://drupal.org/project/efq_views) as your Views backend should make your new Rank field visible to Views.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the default Views backend does not support Entity properties. Instead, it support fields from the Field API and known entity properties such as `nid`. In order to use your custom property as a Views field, you need to either use [EntityFieldQuery Views Backend](http://drupal.org/project/efq_views) ([as suggested by David Watson](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/25224/177)) or provide an implementation of [`hook_views_data()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7) to expose your table and column to Views.